# Construct normal of a plane through three points without using cross product

Tags: geometry

I want to find the normal vector of a plane in 3d that intersects know points $a$, $b$, and $c$. **I do not want to use cross product** because I want this method to apply to arbitrary number of dimensions (finding a $n-1$ dimensional hyperplane in $n$ space that intersects $n$ points).
But I need the resulting normal to be oriented correctly such that the points are arranged counter-clockwise when looking down on the plane.

My first attempt was to use gaussian elimination on:

$\begin{bmatrix}
a_x & a_y & a_z & 1 \\ 
b_x & b_y & b_z & 1 \\ 
c_x & c_y & c_z & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$

which I get from taking the equation for the plane:

$p \cdot n = d$

where $p$ is one of the three points, and stacking these equations and setting $d$ equal to 1. This method producted a normal that is parallel to the correct normal but sometimes points in the opposite direction. I think this might have to do with setting $d$ to 1 but I dont know how else to use gaussian elimination here.

Are there any other techniques that will work for arbitrary dimensions?

Comment: There is no “correct” orientation for the normal, since what you end up with via cross products depends on the order in which you decide to use the three points.

Comment: @amd The points are ordered correctly when given so they should appear counter-clockwise in the sequence $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: How about using a [generalized cross-product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra)?

Comment: I believe that whether or not you get the right orientation using Gaussian elimination to find the null (homogeneous) vector depends on the parity of the dimension of the hyperplane. I.e., depending on how you assign signs to the resulting vector, either all of the even-dimensional vectors are correct and all odd-dimensional ones wrong, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec a$, $\vec b$, and $\vec c$ are not collinear, then the plane is given as $\vec r = \vec a + x(\vec b - \vec a) + y(\vec c - \vec a)$ where $x,y \in K$ where $K$ denotes the scalar field.

This is essentially the translation by $\vec a$ of the $2$-dimensional subspace $\operatorname{span}(\vec b - \vec a, \vec c - \vec a)$.

Comment: thanks but I'm afraid I was not specific enough in my question. I need the normal vector.

Comment: @chuck1 there are multiple normal vectors.

Comment: In three dimensions there would be 2, correct? and they are parallel?

Comment: @chuck1 yes, but in higher dimensions there are infinitely many.

Comment: Are there infinitely many even if I have as many known points (though which the plane must pass) as there are dimensions?

Comment: @chuck1 in $n+3$ dimensions the normal vectors you seek form $S^n$, i.e. unit sphere of $n$ dimensions.

Comment: can you not define a plane in arbitrary dimensions using $p \cdot n = d$ where $n$ is a vector normal to the plane? It seems that this plane has only one normal.

Comment: @chuck1 but this plane has dimension $m-1$ if your vector space has dimension $m$.

Comment: true, why is that a problem?

Comment: @chuck1 because when you said plane I took it to mean something two-dimensional.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I think I should have said hyperplane? does hyperplane imply a $n-1$ dimensional subspace in $n$ dimensional space?

Comment: @chuck1 then the hyperplane isn't defined uniquely by $3$ points.